# Estimating correlation matrix in R with time series?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, correlation

I have a time series of the number of sunspots from 1710 to 1980 base on a dataset from R.

I am trying to estimate the matrix of correlation of the "y" values. I tried to use the cor(.) function from the timeSeries package( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/timeSeries.pdf )(page 64). But it doesn't work.

Let "yp" be my vector of observations from 1710 to 1980(time series object). My code is:

```
CorrelationMatrice=cor(yp,y=NULL,use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson"))
```

Thank you for reading this post.

The error is of the following form:

```
Error in cor(yp, y = NULL, use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson")) : 
  give 'x' and 'y' or 'x' as a matrix
```

I would like that my correlation matrix gives the correlation between each pair of observations ci and cj from yp.

Comment: I do not know this package but (just guessing here!) it looks that the function did not received the proper argument, are you sure `yp` is a matrix?

Comment: No. yp is the vector of observations from 1710 to 1980. However, the package timeSeries with the function cor(.) says that "x" must be " an univariate object of class timeSeries". I converted my vector yp in a time series with as.ts(yp).

Comment: Ok get it. Could you please provide a little piece of your data with `dput`?

Comment: I'm wondering if your terminology is confused. There is no such statistical animal as a correlation of a single vector. Correlation is a a relation of two items. There is such a thing as the auto-correlation function applied to a single vector. Asking for all pairwise something (differences?)  might suggest you instead want a distance matrix.

Comment: Here is a link that shows what is yp: http://pastebin.com/XxVL3zNn

Comment: @BondedDust  I have to create a Bayesian Linear Regression from my time series where: y~(XB, (σ^2) *S)  and S is the matrix of correlation. I tried to estimate it with the R procedure that I mentionned earlier but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mercier - Your time series is simply a vector. You write `cor(yp, y = NULL,`, which means that yp is your 'x', and y = NULL, thus there is no way for cor() to generate a correlation. What are you looking to correlate yp with?

Comment: @scribbles I want to make a correlation matrix for any two combination possible of two elements of yp.

i.e. I want a matrix of 271 x 271.

such that element (ci,cj) should be correlation between ci and cj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are receiving an error is that the time series example you provided (yp) is a vector. If you look closely at the documentation for the timeSeries package, you will see that the sample time series used are matrixes and not vectors, which is why you are receiving the following error message

```
Error in cor(yp, y = NULL, use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson")) : give 'x' and 'y' or 'x' as a matrix
```

If you use a matrix for yp rather than a vector, you will not get an error. 
Example:

```
my_ts <- <- as.data.frame(timeSeries(matrix(rnorm(24), 12), timeCalendar()))

cor(my_ts, y = NULL, use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson"))

           TS.1       TS.2
TS.1 1.00000000 0.02275777
TS.2 0.02275777 1.00000000
```

You could attempt to use you vector for both X and Y `cor(yp, y = yp, use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson"))` and get a correlation matrix that was 271x271, but there wouldn't be much point as you would receive a correlation of 1.

```
cor(yp, y = yp, use = "all.obs", method = c("pearson"))
[1] 1
```

In order you generate the correlation matrix that you are looking for you need to compare two different time series rather than comparing one-time series to itself. For example, you could compare the Dow Jones Industrial Average to the Euro/Dollar exchange rate over a certain period of time.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer!

Comment: @Mercier, if this answer works for you, please click the checkmark next to the answer so that others will know that this question has been resolved. Thanks.